# getOutputStream in Java Stored procedure throws error

Tags: java, oracle, outputstream, java-stored-procedures

I am trying to consume a SOAP web service from a Java Stored procedure and in that I am using getOutputStream() command to write the payload to the connection which is throwing access error as below.

Java call terminated by uncaught Java exception:

```
java.security.AccessControlException:
the Permission (java.net.SocketPermission <Server-Name>:<Port> connect,resolve) 
has not been granted to INFOIFACE.
The PL/SQL to grant this is dbms_java.grant_permission 
( 'INFOIFACE', 'SYS:java.net.SocketPermission', <Server-Name>:<Port>, 'connect,resolve' )
```

But the same access is provided in Oracle DB for the schema and still it shows the error.

```
public class remoteConnection {
    public static String connectToFPH(String destUrl, String pacFile, String cred, String payLoad) throws Exception {

        System.out.println("Inside function");
        BrowserProxyInfo bInfo = new BrowserProxyInfo();        
        bInfo.setType(ProxyType.AUTO);
        bInfo.setAutoConfigURL(pacFile);       
        DummyAutoProxyHandler handler = new DummyAutoProxyHandler();
        try {
            handler.init(bInfo);
        } catch (ProxyConfigException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }

        String basicAuth = "Basic " + javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(cred.getBytes());
        URL url = new URL(destUrl);

        String proxyUrl = "";
        ProxyInfo[] ps = handler.getProxyInfo(url);     
        for(ProxyInfo p : ps){
            proxyUrl = p.toString();
        }

        Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress(proxyUrl.split(":")[0], Integer.valueOf(proxyUrl.split(":")[1])));

        HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection)url.openConnection(proxy);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty ("Authorization", basicAuth);
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=UTF-8");
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setUseCaches(false);
        conn.setAllowUserInteraction(false);

        OutputStream out = conn.getOutputStream();
        OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(out, "UTF-8");
        writer.write(payLoad);
        writer.close();
        out.close();

        String inputLine;
        StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
        if(conn.getResponseCode() == 200)
        {
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));

            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) 
            {
                buf.append(inputLine);
            }
            in.close();
        }
        else
        {
            //throw new Exception("Unable to connect to FPH. Please contact Administrator");
            return "unable to connect";
        }

        conn.disconnect();

        return buf.toString();
    }

}
```

I request help in this regard. Is there some other access required to be provided in Oracle DB?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have run into the Oracle Security Manager.  This is basically, a classical Java `SecurityManager` that is controlled by a database table:

> "As with Java2 security, Oracle Database supports the security classes. Normally, you set the permissions for the code base either using a tool or by editing the security policy file. In Oracle Database, you set the permissions dynamically using DBMS_JAVA procedures, which modify a policy table in the database."

For more information, see:

- ["Security for Oracle Database Java Applications"](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/java.111/b31225/chten.htm#BABFBDGG)

Note that Example 10-1 in the above shows how to grant a Java permission using a DBMS_Java.  (The example shows a `FilePermission` grant.  You will need a `SocketPermission` grant with the relevant attributes.)

Comment: We have provided permissions as "dbms_java.grant_permission( 'INFOIFACE', 'SYS:java.net.SocketPermission', <Server-Name:Port>, 'connect,resolve'). Is there some other access that is necessary?

Comment: 1) Did you use the correct server name and port?  2) Did you `COMMIT`?

Comment: Yes. I have used the right port & server. I can even see the updates in the Db table

Answer (score 0):

The Problem can be in ACL list.
1) Check the network privilages  `SELECT * FROM  user_network_acl_privileges;` for you remote host.
2) If there is not entry about it.
Create new ACL list.

```
declare
 v_acl_name varchar2(30) := 'your_acl_name1.xml';
BEGIN
  DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.CREATE_ACL(acl         => v_acl_name,
                                    description => 'Allow user to make connection',
                                    principal   => 'YOUR_USER',
                                    is_grant    => TRUE,
                                    privilege   => 'connect');

  -- optional
--  DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.ADD_PRIVILEGE(acl       => v_acl_name,
--                                       principal => 'YOUR_USER',
--                                       is_grant  => true,
--                                       privilege => 'resolve');

  DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.ASSIGN_ACL(acl  => v_acl_name,
                                    host => '*'); -- any host
                                    --or 
 /*DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.ASSIGN_ACL(acl  => v_acl_name,
                                    host => '*.stackoverflow.com');
                                    --or     
  DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.ASSIGN_ACL(acl  => v_acl_name,
                                    host => 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xx-ip ');
   */                          
END;
/
COMMIT;
```

Example is for oracle 11 in later versions there were changes.
Link:
[DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e16760/d_networkacl_adm.htm)